# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_default_prefix'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I work on an unfinished application I did not develop myself. I get this error :

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_default_prefix'
```

Going verify the concerned line :

```
for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets_with_inlines(request, obj), inline_instances):
     prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix() # <---- It seems That the error comes from this line
     prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
```

What's wrong please ? I use Django 1.7.

Comment: This is just the code from Django's admin app, which we can assume is not at fault. Where is the code from *your* app - in particular, your admin.py? Where is the traceback?

Comment: It's clear that here `get_formsets_with_inlines( )` is returning a tuple which then figures in the error. It should be returning something else, but if this is working Django code you must look up the calling chain for the source of the problem. You're calling into Django with the wrong arguments somewhere.

Comment: So you misconfigured your admin form inlines. Can you show us your *own* code and the full traceback?

Comment: The problem is that I had this code done by a intern few months ago. I have changed anything yet. He made a copy and paste it seems.

Comment: Even if it was written by an intern and you haven't made any changes yet, nobody can tell you anything if you don't provide the code you're starting from.  Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have made an attempt to fix an *removeInDjango9* warning by changing `get_formsets()` to `get_formsets_with_inlines()`, which unfortunately cause this error.